# Changing variable in partial derivative's

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

I have $u\colon:\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ smooth, $u=u(x,y)$. Consider the following changing of variables:
$$ z=\biggl(\frac{y}{1-a}\biggr)^{1-a},$$
where $a\in(-1,1)$, i want to prove that:
\begin{equation}
y^au_y=u_z.
\end{equation}
I have found this change of variables in [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608640). I tried to apply the chain rule but without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting, $u_z= - u_y (1-a)^a y^a$.May be I'm doing something wrong.